# How to give space after abstract section in elsevier format

Tags: pdftex, elsarticle

Hi i have latex code in the following way after i run my abstract get overlap with introduction section. I want some space after abstract anybody please help.

```
    \PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{elsarticle}
         \documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
         \usepackage{ecrc}

    \volume{00}
    \firstpage{1}
    \journalname{Procedia Computer Science}
    \runauth{}
    \jid{procs}
    \jnltitlelogo{Procedia Computer Science}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}

    \dochead{}

    \title{Comparative Analysis On Health Related Twitter Data}


    \author{B Naga Harish, Dr. Suman Kumar}

    \address{Department of Computer Science, Troy University, AL}

    \begin{abstract}


    \end{abstract}

    \begin{keyword}

    \end{keyword}

    \end{frontmatter}

    \section{Introduction}
    \cite{stieglitz2012political, hu2013exploiting, steele2012health, ahkter2010sentiment, das2014effects,liu2010mining}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{bibfile1}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screen shot for what i explained above]

Comment: can you edit your question to complete your code

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the `ecrc` package?

Comment: @egreg Its elsevier package even i am not sure about i am new to latex please help.

Comment: you have the choice \documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle} or \documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

Comment: Delete \PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{elsarticle} and you have the choice \documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle} for twocolumn or \documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

Comment: [ecrc.sty](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0004/109867/ecrc.sty)

Comment: @touhami `\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Harish what is the problem? it work for me.

Comment: @touhami It says elsevier-logo-5p missing and it stops there what should i do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Harish in elsarticle-ecrc.zip at http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/latex-instructions you find two logo-3p save them as 5p

Comment: @touhami Thank you very much you saved lot of my time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want the `procedia` option, since you are using `ecrc`, along with the `5p` option suggested by [touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235464/how-to-give-space-after-abstract-section-in-elsevier-format#comment557901_235464)? Note that the `ecrc` says to use `3p` with `procedia` to get the output produced by the Word template, so if you need to emulate that, you should not use `5p`. (You will not get two columns but presumably that is intended in that case.)

```
\documentclass[5p,times,procedia]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\volume{00}
\firstpage{1}
\journalname{Procedia Computer Science}
\runauth{}
\jid{procs}
\jnltitlelogo{Procedia Computer Science}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frontmatter}

    \dochead{}

    \title{Comparative Analysis On Health Related Twitter Data}


    \author{B Naga Harish, Dr. Suman Kumar}

    \address{Department of Computer Science, Troy University, AL}

    \begin{abstract}

      \kant[1-2]

    \end{abstract}

    \begin{keyword}

    \end{keyword}

  \end{frontmatter}

  \section{Introduction}

  \kant[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: contained abstract]

Comment: The kantlipsum package doesn't work for me, do you have any other better solution.

Comment: @Harish That package only provides the dummy text to fill the body. Presumably your actual paper contains actual content, so you don't need it. Just delete the package and replace `\kant[]` with your actual text.

Comment: I did but it says elsevier-logo-5p missing.

Comment: @Harish I assume that's a file you need from Elsevier. It is being required by the class/package you are using. It has nothing to do with `kantlipsum`.